# Optional facets as a function parameter

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can you specify a facet parameter that is optional for `facet_wrap()`, without a weird additional label showing up?

For `facet_wrap()`, it works as expected when facets are specified. But if it's `NULL`, there is a weird `(all)` facet. Is it possible to get rid of that facet label without adding another parameter to the function?

```r
foo_wrap <- function(x) {
  ggplot(mtcars) +
    aes(x = mpg, y = disp) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(vars({{ x }}))
}
foo_wrap (cyl) # cylinder facets
foo_wrap (NULL) # how to get rid of "(all)"?
```

[image: foo_wrap (cyl) as expected]
[image: foo_wrap (NULL) how to get rid of "(all)"?]

How can you get rid of "(all)"?

---

## Adding these examples as references in case people find this by searching

Below is an example function with optional facets for `facet_grid()`, where it works as expected:

```r
foo_grid <- function(x) {
  ggplot(mtcars) +
    aes(x = mpg, y = disp) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(rows=NULL, cols=vars({{ x }}))
}
foo_grid (cyl) # cylinder facets
foo_grid (NULL) # no facets, as expected
```

[image: foo_grid (cyl)]
[image: foo_grid (NULL). No facets, as expected.]

Here is an example with hard coded `rows` facetting. Note that you need to call `vars()`:

```r
foo_grid_am <- function(x) {
  ggplot(mtcars) +
    aes(x = mpg, y = disp) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(rows=vars(am), cols=vars({{ x }}))
}
foo_grid_am (cyl) # automatic-manual x cylinder facets
```

[image]

Comment: This feels like a ggplot2 bug, IMO.

Comment: @hadley already ahead of you https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to add a conditional facet layer where I use `rlang::quo_is_null(rlang::enquo(x))` to check whether a faceting variable was provided or not:

Note: I made `NULL` the default.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)

foo_wrap <- function(x = NULL) {
  facet_layer <- if (!rlang::quo_is_null(rlang::enquo(x))) facet_wrap(vars({{ x }}))
  ggplot(mtcars) +
    aes(x = mpg, y = disp) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_layer
}
foo_wrap(cyl)
```

[image]

```r
foo_wrap(NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice Stefan. I was about to post essentially the same answer except add a `if(missing(x))` test to allow the function to be run without having to pass NULL for no facets.

Comment: Great answer, you also beat me. I was going to use `if(!is.null(as.list(match.call())$x))` which seems way worse than both. Glad you posted first.

Comment: Thx @AllanCameron. Yeah. For me having to pass `NULL` for no facets feels awkward, too. Prefer to set optional arguments to `NULL`.

Comment: Thx @AndS. And thx for teaching me about `match.call`. Never used it before. (:

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Yeah, I agree about having `NULL` as default. I just tried to keep the reprexes simple. The solution is surprisingly cumbersome given that it just works with `facet_grid()`.

Comment: @sharoz. Yeah. Strange that passing `NULL` works in facet_grid but not in facet_wrap. Maybe we miss something. :D And yes. Would be interested in a simpler approach as well.

Comment: I've posted an issue because it seems like a consistency/usability issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5000 (Number 5000!). Or, maybe the ggplot devs know of a simpler option.